# How to read .mod files using Python

Tags: python, pandas, file-io

I have a file with extension **.mod.** 
That file contains fields and data under each field, just like every csv files do.
I need to read this .mod file using Python.

Please suggest me a way out in Python using Pandas or any other package that could help me with this.

Thanks!

Comment: can you give us a link to download .mod file?

Comment: @Tilak http://biogeme.epfl.ch/examples/swissmetro/bison/09nested.mod

Comment: Uh what exactly is in the file? My Google search for the extension brings up results for some audio format.

Comment: @juanpa Text only. You may use the link above to see the .mod file. You can open it with Notepad++

Comment: Sorry, that isn't how StackOverflow works. If it is text, there's no reason why you cannot post an example in the question itself.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i am new to stack overflow. Your concern taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows 10, using Python 3.6, I could successfully open the file and read the first line:

```
with open('09nested.mod') as f:
    print(f.readlines()[0])

// File: 09nested.mod

>>>
```

Comment: Thanks! I can at least read the file by the way you have suggested.\